# Count Number of Items In array above 0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have an array

```
array:3 [▼
  1 => "2"
  2 => "2"
  3 => "0"
]
```

I want to count the number of keys which have the value over 0. In the above example I should have the answer 2.

Here's my attempt.

```
return count($input_items > 0);
```

This returns 1

Comment: You probably can google that in 3 min. Also you are  not making any question, you pretend someone else to come arround and code this for you.

Comment: You are one lazy Artisan.... try to read your code `count($input_items > 0)`, what does it even say? It says: `count($input_items larger than zero)`, its simple and it should work if your PHP interpreter is a human. Fortunately PHP interpreter is run by computer so part ($input_items > 0) is binary `compare` function with operator `>` and two inputs `$input_items` and `0` essentially you can "write" it as `>($input_items, 0)` ... which leads to "is $input_items larger than zero?" and answer is either TRUE or FALSE, so ultimately you are counting boolean value.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user clearly hasn't done any research in an attempt to solve this himself.

Comment: @Kyslik you are right sir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) as:

```
count(array_filter($array))
```

If you don’t supply a callback function, it filters all values out that equal false [(boolean conversion)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting).